# Using custom CA certificate with Conda Python on macOS

Tags: python, ssl, conda

At `https://myhost.example.com` I have a my own site with a certificate signed by my own CA.

I am using macOS and I added the custom CA certificate to my macOS Keychain. It works properly in the Apple-provided Python with the following minimal code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://myhost.example.com')
```

---

Now I want to execute the same program in the Miniconda environment (the base one):

I added my CA certificate to `~/miniconda2/ssl/cacert.pem` with:

```
# cat myownca.pem >> ~/miniconda2/ssl/cacert.pem
```

The certificate starts with the following, so I guess it is the proper PEM format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDZzCCAk+gAwIBA...
```

I checked:

```
# python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/ssl/cert.pem', capath='/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/ssl/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/ssl/certs')
```

However the Python program is failing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testinpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://myhost.example.com')
  File "/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asylumine/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myhost.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

What am I missing?